# How to find the value of a column based on a value of another column?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a simple metro line system modeled like this:

- A line has multiple stations.
- Each station has a timetable.
- A timetable contains some time info and a direction that denotes which direction of the line the time info is for.

And my question is, given a timetable, how do I find the terminal station that belongs to the line of that direction?

My tables are structured like this:

```
CREATE TABLE schedule (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    to_start boolean,
    start_time time,
    end_time time,
    station_id REFERENCES station
);

CREATE TABLE station (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar,
    order integer,
    line_id integer REFERENCES line
);

CREATE TABLE line (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar
);
```

If `schedule.to_start` is `true`, it means the direction points to station with an order of `1`, and `false` to `max(order)`.

Here is some sample data:

schedule table

```
 id | to_start | start_time | end_time | station_id 
----+----------+------------+----------+------------
  1 | f        | 06:02:00   | 22:02:00 |          2
  2 | t        | 06:35:00   | 23:07:00 |          2
```

station table

```
 id |     name     | order  | line_id 
----+--------------+--------+---------
  1 | Station A    |      1 |       1
  2 | Station B    |      2 |       1
  3 | Station C    |      3 |       1
  4 | Station D    |      1 |       2
```

line table

```
 id |  name  
----+--------
  1 | Line 1 
  2 | Line 2
```

So if given a `schedule.id` value like `1`, how do I find the corresponding `station.name` which should be `Station C` (because that schedule is of station with id `2`, which belongs to line with id `1` and since `to_start` is `false`, it point to the end of line, which should be `Station C`)?

I use postgresql and my initial try relied on connecting to database multiple times, in which case I begin by selecting the schedule based on the given id, save its `to_start` and `station_id`, then select the corresponding station using the saved `station_id`, save its `line_id`, and based on the value of `to_start` I either select station with `line_id` and an `order` of `1`, or find `max(order)` first and then select station with `line_id` and the max order.

It feels really cumbersome and not letting postgresql make the best optimization possible.

Is there any way to do this with one sql?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question do not post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the suggestion. Edited.

Comment: @hgl What have you tried so far?

Comment: @JohnHC I mentioned it in the bottom of my question. I didn't post code, just described the logic, since it involved saving results to variables and made new queries which seems to be out of scope of sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do:

```
select   ds.*
from     schedule s
join     station  qs on qs.id = s.station_id
join     station  ds using (line_id)
where    s.id = 1
order by ds."order" * case when s.to_start then 1 else -1 end
limit    1
```

Notes:

- `order` is reserved keyword, so it is unwise to use it as a column name
- your schema looks a little odd to me, f.ex. you'll need to duplicate stations, if multiple lines are crossing it

http://rextester.com/OITNB38639

Comment: Thanks. This is pretty ingenious, and thanks for the suggestion, I use `number` in my own code. I use `order` here just to make the intention clearer. And for duplicate stations, do you think it should be many to many? I personally feel treating such station as being different and then use a transfer table to record the duplicates seem to be more flexible.

Comment: @hgl If you really treat them differently, this may be fine. It may even come in handy in some edge-cases. But it will make calculating transfers much harder (if you ever need to do that). -- Many-to-many seems reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with joins. You can do mutiple joins in one query.

```
SELECT * FROM schedule JOIN station on station.id = schedule.station_id JOIN line line.id = schedule.line_id WHERE sechdule.id = '1'
```

more info about joins:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: I'm sorry but I doubt it could be as simple as that, could you make the solution be more specific to the question? Thanks.

Comment: I changed my solution to be more specific to your question.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of CTEs, a new row_number() and some lovely self joins

```
with FirstLast as
(
select a1.*, 
       row_number() over(partition by line_id order by a1.order desc) as order2
from Station a1
)
, Stage2 as
(
select a1.id, a1.name, a2.name as FirstStation, a3.name as LastStation
from FirstLast a1
inner join FirstLast a2
  on a1.line_id = a2.line_id
  and a2.order = 1
inner join FirstLast a3
  on a1.line_id = a3.line_id
  and a3.order2 = 1
)
select x.id, 
       x.name, 
       case 
         when z.to_start = 't' then x.FirstStation 
         else x.LastStation 
       end as TheStation
from schedule z
inner join Stage2 x
  on z.station_id = x.id
```